# saving data into a file c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am having a hard time trying to do this, its like a survey, people have to answer those 5 questions and their answers(data) have to be save into a file.txt then the program have to read the data.Then, lets say that the user answered A for the first question it has to say 20 out of the number of people who did the survey answered A (20/100) the same with the other 5 questions. but im kind lost i dont know how to make the program count how many people took the survey and how to store they answer into a file. PLEASE HELP!

```
int questions = 1;
char answer;

for (int i = 0; i < questions; i++){

    cout << "\t1 - What kind of phone do you prefer? " << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\ta) Iphone    b) Android  c) Windows  d) Other" << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\tAnswer: ";
    cin >> answer;
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "\t2 - What is your favorite flavor? " << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\ta) Chocolate b) Vanilla  c) Strawberry   d) Other" << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\tAnswer: ";
    cin >> answer;
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "\t3 - What is your favorite sport? " << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\ta) Baskteball    b) Baseball c) Hokey    d) Football" << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\tAnswer: ";
    cin >> answer;
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "\t4 - What is your favorite animal? " << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\ta) Cat       b) Dog      c) Bird     d) Other" << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\tAnswer: ";
    cin >> answer;
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "\t5 - What is your favorite season of the year? " << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\ta) Summer    b) Winter   c) Spring   d) Autumn" << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\tAnswer: ";
    cin >> answer;
    cout << "\n";
}



system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: So u want to store one person into a single file? Then count those files?

Answer (score 0):

Google search for "c++ write into file". First hit: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

This should answer all your questions to this.

Short outline:

you can handle the file like cout. Open it and than you write to the file output stream.

Reading is also described there.

But: it seems like you don't really have a solution in your mind. Write in your natural languge a step by step description of the whole process. Note what should be written where in the file so you can read it afterwards. This may be useful too see the task a little bit clearer.

You noticed the downvotes?
You got them because you could have solved this with 5secs googling, your Problem description was very unclear and you begged for help (we are here for helping).

I recommend you to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask